# Relation between a map and its dual map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $U$ be a group which acts on a variety $X$. Then we have a map 
$$
\varphi: U \times X \to X \\
(u, x) \mapsto u.x
$$
The map $\varphi$ has a dual map $\psi$ which is given by
$$
\mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C}[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}[X] \\
f \mapsto \sum f_{(-1)} \otimes f_{(0)},
$$
where $\sum f_{(-1)} \otimes f_{(0)}$ is the Sweedler notation.

I think that the relation between $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is
$$
f(u.x) = (\sum f_{(-1)} \otimes f_{(0)} )(u,x) = \sum f_{(-1)}(u)f_{(0)}(x).
$$
Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct!

I don't think we can say that $\sum f_{(-1)} \otimes f_{(0)}$ is the Sweedler notation.

Instead, I would say if $\varphi^*$ is the dual map of $\varphi$. Since the coordinate ring of $U\times X$ is $\mathbb C[U]\otimes \mathbb C[X]$ (I assume they are affine), we can let $\varphi^*(f)=\sum_{i=1}^m g_i\otimes h_i$, where $g_i\in \mathbb C[U]$ and $h_i\in\mathbb C[X]$.

By definition, we have $\varphi^*(f)(u,x)=f(\varphi(u,x))$. This implies that $$
f(u\cdot x)=\sum_{i=1}^m g_i(u)h_i(x).$$